Use the syntax Namespace['Mytype'] to get a type
I have a generated file (let's call it generated.ts) that gives me something like:
...
export type GetCompanyForEmployeeQueryVariables = Exact<{
  companyId: Scalars['String'];
}>;
export type GetCompanyForEmployeeQuery = { __typename?: 'Query', getCompany?: { __typename?: 'QueryGetCompanyError', source: Source, reasons: Array<GetCompanyRefusalReasons> } | { __typename?: 'QueryGetCompanySuccess', data: { __typename?: 'Company', id: string, name: string, mdmPlatforms: Array<DevicePlatform> } } | null };
export function useGetCompanyForEmployeeLazyQuery(baseOptions?: Apollo.LazyQueryHookOptions<GetCompanyForEmployeeQuery, GetCompanyForEmployeeQueryVariables>) {
    const options = {...defaultOptions, ...baseOptions}
    return Apollo.useLazyQuery<GetCompanyForEmployeeQuery, GetCompanyForEmployeeQueryVariables>(GetCompanyForEmployeeDocument, options);
}
...

What I want to do is to "dynamically" access a certain type inside but I have this error: Cannot use namespace 'GeneratedTypes' as a type.ts(2709).
import type * as Generated from './generated.ts'

type WorkingVariables = GeneratedTypes.GetCompanyForEmployeeQueryVariables;

// error: Cannot use namespace 'GeneratedTypes' as a type.ts(2709)
type NotWorkingVariables = GeneratedTypes['GetCompanyForEmployeeQueryVariables'];


// My usecase looks like (it just for the example)
type ComputedNameFromOtherStrings = Compute<QueryName>
type Variables = GeneratedTypes[ComputedNameFromOtherStrings];


Your import:
import type * as GeneratedTypes from './generated.ts'

It is causing issues because TypeScript treats GeneratedTypes as a runtime value, not a type.
You can try using typeof GeneratedTypes:
type NotWorkingVariables = typeof GeneratedTypes['GetCompanyForEmployeeQueryVariables'];

Or you could replace your import so that when something is a type, you use the keyword type, but if it is not a type, you simply import it.
import {
    type GetCompanyForEmployeeQuery,
    type GetCompanyForEmployeeQueryVariables,
    useGetCompanyForEmployeeLazyQuery
} from "yourmodule";


I'm already import it as a type
import type * as Generated from './generated.ts'

That import will not work because GeneratedTypes is an object. I have added more details.

Yeah but, I want to use the types inside dynamically, check the end of my post :)

The only thing that I can suggest is import * as GeneratedTypes from './generated.ts and type Variables = (typeof GeneratedTypes)[ComputedNameFromOtherStrings];

Which sadly lead to the error property 'GetCompanyForEmployeeQueryVariables' does not exist on type 'typeof import("./generated.td")'. if I use it this way
type Variables = (typeof GeneratedTypes)['GetCompanyForEmployeeQueryVariables'];
